# Dash plotly imshow fails to update on dropdown selection

Tags: plotly-dash

New to Dash-plotly user here. I am trying to draw a bunch of images based on a user choice picked from dropdown. Let us say the synthetic data is like this.

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output,callback
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math


samples = [200,10,5,40,60,100,2,100,9,10]
idx = [n for n in range(10)]

for i,smp in zip(idx,samples):
    if i == 0:
        X = np.full((smp,28, 28), i/10)
        y = np.full((smp,),i)
    else:
        tempx = np.full((smp,28, 28), i/10)
        tempy = np.full((smp,),i)
        X = np.r_[X,tempx]
        y = np.r_[y,tempy]
```

So y is a numpy array of elements with 0 to 9. Number of times each digit appears is determined by samples. Every element of x is y/10 appearing in a 28x28 array.

My objective is to plot random images from X for a user selected value of y from a dropdown. Here's my code.

```
app = Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown([i for i in range(10)],
                 0,
                 id='my_dropdown2'),

    html.Div(dcc.Graph(id='my_picbox'))
])


@callback(
    Output(component_id='my_picbox', component_property='figure'),
    Input(component_id='my_dropdown2', component_property='value')
)

def update_plot(digit):

    x_copy = np.copy(X)
    y_copy= np.copy(y)

    if digit is None:
        digit = 0
    
    lbl_idx = np.where(y_copy==digit)[0]
    num_samples = (min(len(lbl_idx),40))
    choose = np.random.choice(lbl_idx,num_samples)
    
    fig = px.imshow(x_copy[choose, :, :],
                    binary_string=False,
                    zmin=0,
                    zmax=1,
                    facet_col=0,
                    facet_col_wrap=10,
                    color_continuous_scale='rdylgn')
    
    fig.update_layout(height=150*math.ceil(num_samples/10))
    
    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(mode = 'jupyterlab')
```

When I run the code , as expected I see 40 images arranged in 4 rows for digit 0. However, when I select a digit from the dropdown , it goes haywire.
If I select 1, it updates only once. Any further selection doesn't work. Please help